# Adding a foreign key value without a foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables called order and track. 
Is possible to add the `trackingId` of tracking table into `order.trackingId` while adding data into these tables.

Here's I have done so far:

```
public ABDAO ()
        {
            _context = new Entities();
        }
public void AddPackageDetail(Order order, Track parcel)
        {
            _context.Orders.Add(order);
            _context.Track.Add(parcel);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I have tried doing this

```
 var newTrackID = parcel.trackingId == order.TrackingId;
                _context.Order.Add(newTrackingID); //Came up with error
                    _context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

`newTrackID` is a bool (or `newTrackingID` - a guess you made a typo here) because it is a result of the comparison `parcel.trackingId == order.TrackingId`

`_context.Order.Add(...);` here you can add only an Order object. If I am not wrong you do not need to add a new Order object at all.

If `order.TrackingId` is an int (reference to Track object) You should just update TrackingId property in your order instance:

```
order.TrackingId = parcel.trackingId;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

And if `order.TrackingId` is `Track` class, then you should do something like this:

```
order.TrackingId.Add(parcel);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes, if  'parcel.trackingId' is a PK and `order.TrackingId` is a Track object then you can't assign ID to Track object.